# C# - How can i get the count of child elements using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is an extract of the XML i'm using

```
    <AccountNumber>
      <RecordID>A9</RecordID>
      <SegmentLength>14</SegmentLength>
      <Number>6770307103</Number>
    </AccountNumber>
    <PaymentCounter>
      <RecordID>B2</RecordID>
      <SegmentLength>14</SegmentLength>
      <History>99</History>
      <Delinq30Day>00</Delinq30Day>
      <Delinq60Day>00</Delinq60Day>
      <Delinq90PlusDay>00</Delinq90PlusDay>
      <DerogCnt>00</DerogCnt>
    </PaymentCounter>
```

Here I'm trying to identify the number of child elements under AccountNumber and PaymentCounter.

I'm looking for this answer
AccountNumber count = 3
PaymentCounter count = 7

After I get the count, I will use the data to dynamically populate a table.

I tried this : 
int count1 = xmlDocument.Descendants("AccountNumber").Count();

The count() in LINQ to XML will give me the number of times element "AccountNumber" is repeated in the XML, but doesnot give me the number of child elements.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should get descendants element from `AccountNumber` element, not all xml. So, just try something looks like this: `xmlDocument.Descendants("AccountNumber").SelectMany(item=>item.Descendants()).Count()`

Comment: You should parse to parent of AccountNumber and PaymentCount so both end up in the same group.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

`Descendants("AccountNumber")` returns the children, grandchildren, etc. with the name `AccountNumber`. You actually want the children of the `AccountNumber` element.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your sample there is exactly one AccountNumber, assuming this XML fragment is true of the actual document you are processing and the AccountNumber element is a child of the root element you probably want to do this:

```
xmlDocument.Element("AccountNumber").Elements().Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using `xmlDocument.Descendants("AccountNumber").First().Decendants().Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN 
*`XDocument.Descendants`* 
*`Returns a collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, in document order`*

if you so something like the following

var  elements =    xmlDocument.Descendants("AccountNumber").

you will get all the `AccountNumber elements` 
you have to iterate through each element in  order to get the count of each element

```
 foreach (var xElement in elements )
            {
                var acElt= xElement.Descendants().Count(); 

                     //then do your construction here 
            }
```